# How to make pyrogram python filter many channels

Tags: python, pyrogram

I want the pyrogram track library to be able to filter more than 1 channel @app.on_message(filters.chat("test channel"))

I tried @app.on_message(filters.chat(chats=Chats)) but it didn't work..

```
Chats = '@test', '@test', '@test'

@app.on_message(filters.chat(chats=Chats))
```

Comment: make sure you do not need to define a type of middle-ware function to get your desired task and also a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help others to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

`filters.chat()` takes either a `string` representing the username or phone number, an or `integer` representing the chat_id, or a list of the former two.

```py
Chats = [
   "username",
   "49123456789",  # phone number with international prefix
   789456123  # chat_id
]
@app.on_message(filters.chat(Chats))
```

See Pyrogram's Documentation on the available Filters and how to use them:

- https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/filters#pyrogram.filters.chat
- https://docs.pyrogram.org/topics/use-filters